# jQuery v1.7.1, different contents of 'this' in IE and Chrome/FF

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure if it's a bug in jQuery, FF/Chrome or IE or just expected behavior. Unfortunately I don't know jQuery that well to tell if following script should give the same results under different browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="c">
        <form name="login" action="https://my_domain.com/my_login_script.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="sss" />
            <input type="text" name="password" value="pass" />
            <input type="submit" value="go" />
            </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#c").find('form[name=login]').submit(function() {
            alert($(this).serialize());
            $('#c').html("");
            alert($(this).serialize());
            alert($(this).html()); // empty string in IE, contents of <form> under FF
            return false;
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What it does:

1. Assigns handler for submit event to form 'login' contained in div "#c"
2. In the event handler form is serialized and displayed in alert box.
3. Contents of div "#c" is changed to empty string.
4. Form is again serialized and output string displayed in alert box.
5. Contents of 'this' is displayed in alert box - it's empty in IE and has some html in FF/Chrome

In FF/Chrome alert boxes show:

1. email=sss&password=pass
2. email=sss&password=pass // The same output as above, 'this' has not changed?

In IE9 however:

1. email=sss&password=pass
2. "" // Empty string

Is it a bug in jQuery?

Comment: could you use $(this).html('') instead of $('#c') ? I tried it and this returns empty on 2nd alert on chrome.

Comment: So the problem seems to be how jQuery handles serialization of detached forms in the browsers. What happens if you use `$(this).detach();` instead of `$('#c').html("");`?

Comment: Andy: I could, but I'm not trying to solve any problem here. I found this by accident and was wondering if it's a bug.

Comment: Felix Kling: This would probably work, but I think it's not an issue with serialization. If You'll put alert($(this).html()) before 'return false;' You'll find out that contents of 'this' has changed to empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's more of how the browser handles the `.innerHTML` property than a jQuery bug (as jQuery calls innerHTML, which the browser would use to construct/reconstruct a DOM tree). See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/bhKCu/1/ (if it were a jQuery bug, that should behave the same no matter which browser as it uses `innerHTML` instead of `$.html()` right?).

[From jQuery.html():](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

> This method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may
>   not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided.

From jQuery 1.7.1:

```
html: function( value ) {
        if ( value === undefined ) {
            return this[0] && this[0].nodeType === 1 ?
                this[0].innerHTML.replace(rinlinejQuery, "") :
                null;
    // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
    } else if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test( value ) &&
        (jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace || !rleadingWhitespace.test( value )) &&
        !wrapMap[ (rtagName.exec( value ) || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase() ] ) {

        value = value.replace(rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>");

        try {
            for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
                // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
                if ( this[i].nodeType === 1 ) {
                    jQuery.cleanData( this[i].getElementsByTagName("*") );
                    this[i].innerHTML = value; // HERE
                }
            }

        // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
        } catch(e) {
            this.empty().append( value );
        }

    } else if ( jQuery.isFunction( value ) ) {
        this.each(function(i){
            var self = jQuery( this );

            self.html( value.call(this, i, self.html()) );
        });

    } else {
        this.empty().append( value );
    }

    return this;
},
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I'm still not convinced if it's not a jQuery bug. I would expect from jQuery to protect user from browser specific code. Also documentation on jQuery.html() does not settle this. Returning transformed, yet somehow equivalent html is quite different from returning empty string.

Comment: True - you're getting at that jQuery SHOULD normalise the behaviour of innerHTML right? This is probably true, as I believe it normalises behaviour of certain other JS functions cross-browser.